# WPF Grid not showing

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, user-interface

[My Sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVysc.png)

**What it should look like**

[image: What it should look like]

**What it looks like**

[image: What it looks like]

So I'm not sure why it's not showing the top, 
can someone help?
and I can't explain more. Because I don't know what to do and I'm
not sure what should fix it. The videos I've watched on WPF
are really bad and I can't understand them.

```
<Window x:Class="EasyMath.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EasyMath"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Easy Math" Height="450" Width="580.96" Icon="Icon.png" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" Background="#FF2F3542" Foreground="Black" WindowStyle="None">
<Grid Margin="0,-45,0,0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="151*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="430*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="41*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="409*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="#FF2F3542" Margin="-1,0,0,10">
        <Button x:Name="QuitApp" Content="Button" Margin="550,5,6,5" Background="#FFFF4757" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}" Click="QuitApplication"/>
        <Button Content="Button" Margin="520,5,37,5" Background="#FFFFA502" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}"/>
        <Button Content="Button" Margin="489,5,67,5" Background="#FF2ED573" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Easy Math" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" Height="35" Width="112" FontSize="24" Margin="10,-2,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Please share some code, we can't help you without additional info

Comment: I've added the code.

Comment: replace grid margin -45 to 0

Answer (score 0):

Remove the -45 from root Grid Margin. With this you are saying the root grid should indent to top for 45 pixels effectively hidding the title bar.

As a matter of fact you can completely remove the Margin from root grid.

EDIT:

Looking at your sketch this can be something you might be looking for.

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Easy Math"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
        ResizeMode="CanMinimize" AllowsTransparency="True" 
        Background="Transparent" 
        WindowStyle="None">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="titleBarButton">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="25"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="#FF2F3542">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Easy Math" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" FontSize="24" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,10,0">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource titleBarButton}" Background="#FF2ED573"/>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource titleBarButton}" Background="#FFFFA502"/>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource titleBarButton}" Background="#FFFF4757"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Height="10" Background="Transparent"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Background="#FF2F3542">
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: But I want it to have that space. I'll quickly add my Sketch.

Comment: It seems you do not understand what margin does. I suggest you read up a bit on it. Also, if you take a look at VisualStudio XAML design you will see what the visible area will be. It is indicated by a blue border and it clearly says that the title bar will not be visible.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that you might be coming from WinForms background and are trying to "work with" designer. This is not the way of WPF. You should work in XAML.

Comment: "This is not the way of WPF" - strange statement. it is just wpf designer worse than winforms (or not worse per se, but doesn't support well multitude of layout options available)

Comment: It's certainly not the way I'd develop with WPF. If you drag drop controls then you're you'll likely get large fixed margins and your app may well only work as expected on a machine matches your monitor size settings.